# I start an NSTimer with the play button, but want to end it with the press of the stop button, how would I accomplish this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, nstimer

I have an NSTimer that begins when I press play and it does its thing. But I want it to stop/invalidate when I press the stop button. The problem is I start the timer in the method that handles the play press, but want to invalidate it within the method that handles the stop press.

How would I end it?

Should I make an NSTimer instance that the whole view controller class can access?

Comment: -(IBAction)stop:(id)sender{[timer invalidate];} i think it is invalidate.

Comment: yeah you will have to save the timer somewhere, probably as an iVar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I make an NSTimer instance that the whole view controller class
>   can access?

This is the solution, yes.